# How to use partition to solve top-k problem with duplicates?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Given an array and a number k where k is smaller than the size of the array, we need to find the k’th smallest element in the given array.

I'm confused when there are duplicates in the array.
Clearly, my algorithm below will be stuck when trying to find the 3rd element in [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
How to deal with such an issue?

The Function below uses the Quick-select Algorithm to find out the k'th smallest element.

```
int findTopK(int L, int R, int K) {
    if (L == R) return arr[L];
    int i = L, j = R;
    int pivot = arr[R];
    while (true) {
        while (i <= R && arr[i] < pivot) i++;
        while (j >= L && arr[j] >= pivot) j--;
        if (i >= j) break;
        swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        i++; j--;
    }
    //[L, j] [j+1, R]
    //left: < pivot
    //right: >= pivot

    if (j - L + 1 < K) return findTopK(j+1, R, K - (j - L + 1));
    else return findTopK(L, j, K);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem...?

Comment: You could use a *fat pivot* i.e. swapping all equal pivot values into the range `j <= k <= l` where `j` denotes the first of the equal `k`-th elements and `l` denotes the last.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution to avoid being stuck in the situation described above.
This function can consistently narrow the range of the target interval.
Also, @BeyelerStudios, *fat pivot* is exactly the standard solution to this issue. Thank you for your generous sharing!

```
int findTopK(int L, int R, int K) {
    int i = L, j = R - 1;
    int pivot = arr[R];
    while (true) {
        while (i <= R && arr[i] < pivot) i++;
        while (j >= L && arr[j] >= pivot) j--;
        if (i >= j) break;
        swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
    swap(arr[R], arr[j+1]);
    //[L, j], j+1, [j+2, R]
    //left: < pivot
    //equal: pivot
    //right: >= pivot

    if (j+1 - L + 1 == K) return pivot;

    if (j+1 - L + 1 < K) return findTopK(j+2, R, K - (j+1 - L + 1));
    else return findTopK(L, j, K);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method based on "classic" Hoare partition scheme:

```
int QuickSelectr(int a[], int lo, int hi, int k )
{
    if (lo == hi)                           // recurse until lo == hi
        return a[lo];
    int p = a[(lo+hi)/2];                   // Hoare partition
    int i = lo - 1;
    int j = hi + 1;
    while (1){
        while (a[++i] < p);
        while (a[--j] > p);
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
    }
    if(k <= j)
        return QuickSelectr(a, lo, j-0, k); // include a[j]
    else
        return QuickSelectr(a, j+1, hi, k); // exclude a[j]
}

// parameter check
int QuickSelect(int *a, int lo, int hi, int k)
{
    if(a == (int *)0 || k < lo || k > hi || lo > hi)
        return 0;
    return QuickSelectr(a, lo, hi, k);
}
```

---

Example test code. On my system, N == 8 takes about 5 seconds, N == 9 takes about 2 minutes.

```
#define N (8)
int main()
{
int a[N] = {0};
int b[N];
int c[N];
int i, j;
    while(1){
        memcpy(b, a, N*sizeof(int));
        std::sort(b+0, b+N);
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
            memcpy(c, a, N*sizeof(int));
            i = QuickSelect(c, 0, N-1, j);
            if(i != b[j])
                break;
        }
        i = N-1;
        while(1){
            if(++a[i] != N || i == 0)
                break;
            a[i--] = 0;
        }
        if(a[0] == N)
            break;
    }
    if(a[0] == N)
        printf("passed\n");
    else
        printf("failed\n");         
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, but how to prove that this program won't get stuck when it comes to the bottom cases..

Comment: @KningTG - I updated my answer with example test code that tests 8 "digit" patterns, each selecting 0th through 7th element. (Setting N = 9 will take about 26 times as long).